# How to hide ios navigation bar back button in xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, uinavigationbar, back-button-control

I have created a simple applicaton in xamarin with 2 screens.

Here in second screen, the back button should not appear on the navigation bar.

Can anyone please help me how to hide this button?

Comment: Are u running on iOS7?

Comment: no. I am working on ios 8.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the back button like this:

```
NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton (true, false);
```